# Class/self problem

Tags: python, self

Here's my code:

```
class Pop(object):
    def holder(self):
        self.boobs = 16
        self.sent = "pop"
    def together(self):
        print "%s : %i" % (self.sent, self.boobs)

pop = Pop()

pop.together()
```

Shouldn't this print "pop : 16"? Sorry for the odd variable names :P

Also, I'm new to self. Thanks.

Comment: `foo` `bar` and `baz` are often used for example variables, or `eggs` and `spam` in Python code. They might provide less distractions (unless you *really* like eggs).

Answer (score 10, accepted):

In your example, you should first call `holder`, because that sets the variable to 16.
I think you meant to do this:

```
class Pop(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.boobs = 16
        self.sent = "pop"
    def together(self):
        print "%s : %i" % (self.sent, self.boobs)

pop = Pop()

pop.together()
```